# how to handle System.AccessViolationException occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, krypton-toolkit

i am making an windows application in c#...

and for that i am using sqlexpress for database and componentfactory's krypton tools for UI components...

i am running this application on x86 plateform...

application works fine..but sometimes when i close the form **System.AccessViolationException in System.Windows.Forms.dll** comes on dispose...

i added `<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true" />` into app.config under `<runtime></runtime>`...

i also added `[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]` upon main function and dispose...

still this error not solved...

i am attaching an screen shot image..kindly look at image also..
thanks in advance..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you set `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` attribute, still you need to wrap your code in `try catch`

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions] 
public void TheFunction()
{ 
   try
   {
       // Catch any exceptions in your code
   }
   catch (Exception e) 
   {
        System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: that works..actually first i added try catch but hadn't put `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions`...with both exceptions handles well..